react-native NativeModules is {} - can't access react native package in top-level app
I've created a React Native Package (extends ReactPackage) for Android.  I've created all of the supporting .kt files. However, NativeModules is an empty object ({}) when I try to access it from within my top-level React component:
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { IntentModule } = NativeModules;
I've validated that IntentModulePackage.init() gets called (with log output) - but createNativeModules() does not get called (no log output). In addition - MainApplication.getPackages() logs the following info:
React Packages: [com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage@7bcb47f, com.adac1001.mediamanager.IntentModulePackage@391bc4c]
Any idea what this state reflects exactly?  I guess IntentModulePackage gets basic initialization with metadata but createNativeModules() never gets hit for some reason - so NativeModules never gets populated with it?
But the "React Packages" log output above also reflects "MainReactPackage" which also does not appear to be reflected in NativeModules - so maybe there are multiple issues here.  I've tried multiple debug scenarios with multiple AI bots - and this is the best problem statement that I can discern atm.  Any idea what the issue might be here or how to debug further?  kt classes below.
====
package com.myorg.myapp

import android.app.Application
import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader
import java.util.*
import com.adac1001.mediamanager.IntentModulePackage 

class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {

    private val mReactNativeHost = object : ReactNativeHost(this) {
        override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG
        }

        override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> {
            val packages = listOf(
                MainReactPackage(),
                IntentModulePackage() // Register the package here
            )
            Log.d("MainApplication", "React Packages: $packages")
            return packages
        }

        override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String {
            return "index"
        }
    }

    override val reactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost
        get() = mReactNativeHost

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.d("MainApplication", "onCreate called")
        super.onCreate()
        SoLoader.init(this, false)
    }
}

====
package com.myorg.myapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.fabricEnabled
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule

class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {

    override fun getMainComponentName(): String = "MediaManager"

    override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate =
        DefaultReactActivityDelegate(this, mainComponentName, fabricEnabled)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate called")

        // Handle the incoming share intent
        if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Intent action is SEND")
            if (intent.type == "text/plain") {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Intent type is text/plain")
                handleSendText(intent) // Handle text being sent
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleSendText(intent: Intent) {
        val text = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
        Log.d("MainActivity", "handleSendText called with text: $text")
        text?.let {
            // Send the text to React Native
            sendEventToReactNative(it)
        }
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        setIntent(intent)
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onNewIntent called")

        // Handle the new intent
        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND && intent.type == "text/plain") {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "New Intent action is SEND and type is text/plain")
            handleSendText(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun sendEventToReactNative(sharedText: String) {
        val reactContext = reactInstanceManager?.currentReactContext
        reactContext?.let {
            it
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter::class.java)
                .emit("ShareText", sharedText)
        }
    }
}

====
package com.myorg.myapp

import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager

class IntentModulePackage : ReactPackage {

    init {
        Log.d("IntentModulePackage", "IntentModulePackage initialized")
    }

    override fun createNativeModules(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<NativeModule> {
        Log.d("IntentModulePackage", "enter createNativeModules")
        val modules = listOf(IntentModule(reactContext))
        Log.d("IntentModulePackage", "createNativeModules: $modules")
        return modules
    }

    override fun createViewManagers(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<ViewManager<*, *>> {
        return emptyList()
    }
}

====
package com.myorg.myapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments

class IntentModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
    private var receivedIntent: Intent? = null

    init {
        Log.d("IntentModule", "IntentModule initialized")
    }

    override fun getName(): String {
        return "IntentModule"
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun getSharedText(promise: Promise) {
        Log.d("IntentModule", "getSharedText called")
        receivedIntent?.let {
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEND == it.action && it.type == "text/plain") {
                val sharedText = it.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
                val map = Arguments.createMap()
                map.putString("sharedText", sharedText)
                promise.resolve(map)
                Log.d("IntentModule", "Shared text resolved: $sharedText")
            } else {
                promise.resolve(null)
                Log.d("IntentModule", "Intent action not ACTION_SEND or type not text/plain")
            }
        } ?: run {
            promise.resolve(null)
            Log.d("IntentModule", "Received intent is null")
        }
    }

    fun setReceivedIntent(intent: Intent) {
        receivedIntent = intent
        Log.d("IntentModule", "Intent received and set")
    }
}

